# 3 threads per request

Tags: multithreading, spring-boot, tomcat

I have a spring boot app that will be used on a fairly popular e-commerce platform. I need to create 3 threads to run Cassandra queries in parallel with some business logic to make the service performant. Is this unheard of? I have barely used threads in my young career.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That right. I usually create batch to query cassandra. Use ThreadPool query cassandra to make the service performant